# `cd ..` command takes me to the Trash directory

Tags: command-line, cd-command

I was surprised when this happened and am trying to understand under what circumstances this is possible.

[image: terminal screenshot]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Does this happen at all the times or when you activate ``myenv`` environment?

Comment: Did you delete the `send_email` folder just before you tried this?

Comment: It just happened once. As to whether I deleted the send_email folder, perhaps, I can't remember. But that appears to be a very clear explanation if that is the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you delete a directory using GUI or outside the terminal. But in the terminal, you are still in the directory you have deleted recently.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a directory in the terminal and change the working directory to the new one.

   ```
   mkdir test_directory
   cd ./test_directory
   ```
2. Now delete the recently created folder using GUI (e.g. Files in Ubuntu).
3. After that, use `cd ..` in your terminal where you created your folder. Your current working directory will now be something like `~/.local/share/Trash/files`.